# SQL How to add columns from another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, XMemberT and VMemberT and I want add certain details into an extra column for VMemberT. (If ID matches, add name and age)

I need the end results where the added columns appear on the left side of VMemberT

I've been stuck trying to figure a way to get the desired results out. May I ask for some help, please?

Comment: Add columns to a new table? Or populate the columns in the new table based off ID?

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Comment: You'll want to use a join for this. Your sql will be something like `SELECT VMemberT.*, XMemberT.age, XMemberT.Name FROM VMemberT LEFT OUTER JOIN XMemberT ON VMemberT.MemberID = XMemberT.MemberID;` (Obviously guessing a bit that `VMemberT.MemberID` column name in that ON clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Join for Refrence purpose use this link
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp